# Check for Network Connection

Tags: go, ssh, connection

How can I check if I am able to connect to a server via ssh before running a program on it?

This is how I am connecting to a server:
`cli := ssh.NewSSHClient(conf.User, randomServer)`

and I would like to either use switch or an if statement like:

```
switch cli := ssh.NewSSHClient(conf.User, randomServer) {
case successful:
    fmt.Println("Good morning!")
case fail:
    fmt.Println("Good afternoon.")
}
```

establish connection:

```
func NewSSHClient(user string, hostname string) *SSHClient{
  sock, err := net.Dial("unix", os.Getenv("SSH_AUTH_SOCK"))
  if err != nil {
    logrus.Fatal(err)
  }

  agent := agent.NewClient(sock)
  signers, err := agent.Signers()
  if err != nil {
    logrus.Fatal(err)
  }
  auths := []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(signers...)}
  cfg := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: user,
    Auth: auths,
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),

  }
  cfg.SetDefaults()

  return &SSHClient{
    User: user,
    Hostname: hostname,
    Config: cfg,
  }
}

// Use one connection per command.
// Catch in the client when required.
func (cli *SSHClient)ExecuteCmd(command string){
  conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", cli.Hostname+":22", cli.Config)
  if err!=nil {
    logrus.Infof("%s@%s", cli.Config.User, cli.Hostname)
    logrus.Info("Hint: Add you key to the ssh agent: 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa'")
    logrus.Fatal(err)
  }
  session, _ := conn.NewSession()
  defer session.Close()
  var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
  session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf
  err = session.Run(command)
  if err != nil {
    logrus.Fatalf("Run failed:%v", err)
  }
  logrus.Infof(">%s", stdoutBuf.Bytes())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I check if I am able to connect to a server via ssh before running a program on it?

Don't.

Just attempt the connection. If it doesn't work, you'll get an error. Based on that error, you can do whatever you want--retry the connection, try another server, exit the program, or make toast.

If you were to use the standard SSH library, for instance it would look something like this:

```
cli := ssh.NewClient( ... )
conn, err := cli.Dial( ... )
if err != nil {
    // The connection failed, so do something else
}
```

Comment: Yes. But I want to do something else when it doesn't work.

Comment: @user6942447 Great. So then do that, based on the error you receive.

Comment: `Do you know how I can solve this issue?` -- what issue?

Comment: No. I really need that.

Comment: You really need what?

Comment: The issue is that I do not know if the server is online. If not it would change/switch to another one

Comment: I really need to check if the `randomServer` is reachable.

Comment: yes. The way to check that _is by connecting to it_.

Comment: Yes but how can I do that in the if clause

Comment: I think we mean the same thing.

Comment: I want to know if the server is reachable and else to move on with another one. I do not know how to check if it is.

Comment: If you get an error when trying to connect, then the server isn't reachable.

Comment: I know. But how can I check that? You are really not helpful right now

Comment: How can you check what? You are not asking good questions right now.

Comment: For the error. Look: 

if serverIsReachable {
  do something
else {

Comment: When you attempt _any_ network connection in Go, as with most method calls, you'll get an error. Check if that error is nil:  `if err != nil { // connection failed so do something else }`

Comment: No. It doesn't work. I establish the connection in a different file

Comment: okay. this is how i am establishing a connection (will edit question) and I will not be able to check for an error in the main function/file.

Comment: You're already checking for errors... I don't know what else you want.

Comment: yes. but it will stop then. how can i filter that in my main file?

Comment: filter what? I don't know what that means.  If you don't want your program to stop when it encounters an error, then make it do something else. That's up to you.

Comment: I need to know in my main file if the connection can be established. How can I do that. That is what i need

Comment: Check the error. If you got an error, _the connection could not be established_. It's as simple as that.

Comment: If you want to know more about _why_ the connection could not be established, examine the error value directly. You may get an [AddrError](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#AddrError) indicating that the address is wrong, a [DNS Error](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DNSError) indicating a problem doing DNS lookups, or any number of other error types which give you specific info.